# Windows 10 scans and repairs drive after using Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu in UEFI in parallel with my Windows 10.

It's not a major problem.  My system easily boots to Ubuntu but whenever I reboot to Windows after Ubuntu, it shows

```
scanning and repairing the drive: 100% done
```

(note: Ubuntu is installed on this drive) and it takes longer to boot than from Windows to Windows only.

Comment: **Note:** *Ubuntu 15.10 went End-of-Life in July 2016 (last month).*

Comment: This issue is due to incompatibility in Ubuntu's handling of the 'Windows' formatted drive in question. Each Windows variant updates files/directories is a slightly different manner, and Windows does not expect (or accept) that another OS may have added or changed any files. *The same issue occurs for a shared partition between slightly different versions of Windows.* **You may be able to resolve by doing less changes to the partition (files/folders) under Ubuntu.**

Comment: You should install Ubuntu on a dedicated ext4 partition. Windows doesn't recognize ext partitions, hence no more (unnecessary repairs).